# How to itterare through dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to list through items in column 2 named 'Teams'

I tried this..

```
for team in df['Teams']:
```

also tried

```
for team in df['Teams'].values:
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve after iterating? can you post a sample df? and an expected output? most pandas solutions are vectorized which doesnt require looping. you may also want to look at `iterrows()` , Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to find specific teams from the list.

Comment: Providing an example of your problem and the result you are going to achieve helps you be clear and other users understand the problem.

Comment: you mean `df[df.Teams.isin(teamlist)]` ? if not i suggest you go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and create an example and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your 'df' looks like :

```
>       Team   Score
    0   Cats      9
    1   Dogs      7
```

You can iterate through the column 'Team' by doing:

```
for i in df.get('Team'):
  print(i)

> Cats
  Dogs
```

Comment: but this doesnt require loop? `df['Team']` will give you this, let me know if I am misunderstanding. :) Thanks

Comment: @anky_91 They wanted to iterate over the values, so based on the behavior they're looking for I gave an answer. But yes you can definitely get a list of values by simply doing  df['Team']

Comment: Okay, got it. :) I am still stuck at the first question(why iterate) But that answer has to be answered by the OP. :)

Comment: Sorry, that original code worked. There was an syntax error. I was trying to match teams in team col to another list. I don't know how to post code. I'm new here:)